# How to fix: "undefined response from fetch" Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fetch-api

Been trying to fetch a link/image from an open API from the following guide: https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/rest-api.html#using-node-fetch
but it is not working. I keep getting an undefined response.

Already tried making async functions and so on but not getting any closer.
Also surrounded it by try-catch clausule to debug but not finding the answer.

```
    module.exports = {
        name: 'poes',
        description: 'Laat een random poes foto zien',
        async execute(message, args) {

                const fetch = require('node-fetch');
                const {body} = await fetch('https://aws.random.cat/meow').then(response => response.json());

                message.channel.send(body.file);

        },
    };
```

And this is where it is used:

```
    client.on('message', message => {
            if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

            const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
            const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

            if (!client.commands.has(command)) return;

            try {
                client.commands.get(command).execute(message, args);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
                message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
            }

        }
    );
```

Expected result following the Guide should be a random cat image.

Comment: does your json have a body in it?

Comment: You are correct it did not have "body" in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation you're using is incorrect in a couple of ways:

```
const {body} = await fetch('https://aws.random.cat/meow').then(response => response.json())
```

1. That line assumes `fetch` doesn't fail (with a 404, for instance). This is such a common mistake that I've [written it up on my anemic little blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html). `fetch`'s promise only rejects on *network errors*, not HTTP errors. You have to check `response.ok` or `response.status`.
2. That the parsed result will have a `body` property.
3. It uses `then` in an `async` function, which makes very little sense.

But if I go to `https://aws.random.cat/meow`, I get this JSON:

```
{"file":"https:\/\/purr.objects-us-east-1.dream.io\/i\/img_20131111_094048.jpg"}
```

There's no `body` there, which is why you get `undefined` for it.

Here's an example fixing all three issues:

```
const response = await fetch('https://aws.random.cat/meow');
if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("HTTP status " + response.status);
}
const body = await response.json();
//    ^---^---- no { and }, we don't want to destructure
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will try this in a minute and let you know!

Comment: Thanks so much this worked!

I do have a question left though:"
Does the function still need to be async?

Comment: @Darcula - If you're going to use `await`, yes, because `await` is only valid in `async` functions. The alternative, in a non-`async` function, is to return the result of `fetch('https://aws.random.cat/meow').then(response => { if (!response.ok) { throw new Error("HTTP status " + response.status); } return response.json(); });` (which is a promise of the JSON).

Comment: I used the answer you provided! clicked the other answer by mistake. So that should mean all problems are solved right? (will read the link you provided!)

Comment: @Darcula - Should mean that, yup! :-)

Answer (score 1):

The response from the api is

```
{
  "file": "https://purr.objects-us-east-1.dream.io/i/r958B.jpg"
}
```

And you are saying it is

```
{ 
  "body" : {
    "file" : ""
  }
}
```

So you need to dump the brackets

```
const body = await fetch('https://aws.random.cat/meow')
    .then(response => response.json());
```

or you need to look for file instead

```
const { file } = await fetch('https://aws.random.cat/meow')
    .then(response => response.json());
console.log(file)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, i will try this in a few minutes!